# NHibernate cascading save

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-cascade

This is trying to insert null into Comment.BlogArticleID.

The following GenericADOException appeared:
"could not insert: [NHibernate__OneToMany.BO.Comment][SQL: INSERT INTO Comment (Name) VALUES (?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]"

The following Inner-Exception appeared: 
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BlogArticleID', table 'Relationships_Test_OneToMany.dbo.Comment'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

**I need a unidirectional mapping.** The answer provided yet is talking about bi-directional mapping.

Does NHibernate cascade save works with native ID generator?

### DB tables:

BlogArticle{ID, Name}, where in case of ID, Identitity=true.

Comment{ID, Name, BlogArticleID}, where in case of ID, Identitity=true.

### Comment.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping
  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  assembly="NHibernate__OneToMany.BO"
  namespace="NHibernate__OneToMany.BO"
  default-access="property">

  <class name="Comment" table="Comment">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

public class Comment
    {
        private int _id;
        public virtual int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public Comment()
        {
        }

        public Comment(string name)
        {
            this._name = name;
        }

        private string _name;
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }   
    }
```

### BlogArticle.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping 
  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  namespace="NHibernate__OneToMany.BO"
  assembly="NHibernate__OneToMany.BO"
  default-access="property">
  <class name="BlogArticle"  table="BlogArticle">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />

    <bag name="Comments" cascade="all" >
      <key column="BlogArticleID" />
      <one-to-many class="Comment" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


public class BlogArticle
    {
        private int _id;
        public virtual int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _name;
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private IList _depts;
        public virtual IList Comments
        {
            get { return _depts; }
            set { _depts = value; }
        }   
    }
```

### Main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlogArticle ba = new BlogArticle();
        ba.Name = "Humanity";
        ba.Comments = new List<Comment>();
        ba.Comments.Add(new Comment("Comm1"));
        ba.Comments.Add(new Comment("Comm2"));
        ba.Comments.Add(new Comment("Comm3"));

        Repository<BlogArticle> rep = new Repository<BlogArticle>();
        rep.Save(ba);
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    {
        ISession _session;

        public Repository()
        {
            _session = SessionFactoryManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        private void Commit()
        {
            if (_session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        private void Rollback()
        {
            if (_session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                //_session.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void BeginTransaction()
        {
            _session.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public void Save(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BeginTransaction();

                _session.Save(obj);                

                this.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }            
        }

        void IRepository<T>.Save(IList<T> objs)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BeginTransaction();

                for (Int32 I = 0; I < objs.Count; ++I)
                {
                    _session.Save(objs[I]);
                }

                this.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        void IRepository<T>.Update(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BeginTransaction();

                _session.Update(obj);

                this.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        void IRepository<T>.Update(IList<T> objs)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BeginTransaction();

                for (Int32 I = 0; I < objs.Count; ++I)
                {
                    _session.Update(objs[I]);
                }

                this.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        void IRepository<T>.Delete(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BeginTransaction();

                _session.Delete(obj);

                this.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }  
        }

        void IRepository<T>.Delete(IList<T> objs)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BeginTransaction();

                for (Int32 I = 0; I < objs.Count; ++I)
                {
                    _session.Delete(objs[I]);
                }

                this.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        T IRepository<T>.Load<T>(object id)
        {
            return _session.Load<T>(id);
        }

        public IList<T> Get<T>(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
            criteria.SetFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize);
            if (pageSize > 0)
            {
                criteria.SetMaxResults(pageSize);
            }
            return criteria.List<T>();
        }

        public T Get<T>(object id)
        {
            return _session.Get<T>(id);
        }

        public IList<T> Get<T>()
        {
            return Get<T>(0, 0);
        }

        public IList<T> Get<T>(string propertyName, bool Ascending)
        {
            Order cr1 = new Order(propertyName, Ascending);

            IList<T> objsResult = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).AddOrder(cr1).List<T>();

            return objsResult;
        }

        public IList<T> Find<T>(IList<string> strs)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.IList<NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion> objs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ICriterion>();
            foreach (string s in strs)
            {
                NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion cr1 = NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Sql(s);
                objs.Add(cr1);
            }
            ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
            foreach (ICriterion rest in objs)
                _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).Add(rest);

            criteria.SetFirstResult(0);
            return criteria.List<T>();
        }

        public void Detach(T item)
        {
            _session.Evict(item);
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146604/why-isnt-my-nhibernate-bag-collection-setting-the-parent-id-of-the-children-dy

Comment: maybe `<key column="BlogArticleID" not-null="true" />`?

Comment: Did you try the changes in the link posted by Isaac Cambron? Also, with which NH version are you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The key column of the associated class (Comment.BlogArticleID) must be nullable in the database**. NHibernate will insert rows leaving this column NULL and then perform an update to set the key.

Adding not-null="true" to the key element would not work, as this attribute is only used by the schema export tool.

Note that the failing insert includes a select for the generated identity for the new child row.

Comment: Actually, it can´t  be "not-null" in the mapping, not in the DataBase. I´m running Nhibernate 3.3 and my bag is a nullable and My relation Many to One is a nullable too, but the database is set to don´t accept  null values and this works when I save cascade

Answer (score 1):

you haven't mapped the Article to the Comment:

```
<hibernate-mapping
  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  assembly="NHibernate__OneToMany.BO"
  namespace="NHibernate__OneToMany.BO"
  default-access="property">

  <class name="Comment" table="Comment">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" />
    <many-to-one name="BlogArticle" column="BlogArticleID" />   <----------
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

public class Comment
    {
        private int _id;
        public virtual int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public Comment() { }

        public Comment(int id, string name, BlogArticle article) <------------
        {
            this._id = id;
            this._name = name;
            this._blogArticle = article; <------------
        }

        private string _name;
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }   

        private BlogArticle _blogArticle;       <------------
        public virtual BlogArticle Name       <------------
        {
            get { return _blogArticle; }       <------------
            set { _blogArticle= value; }       <------------
        }   

    }
```

Comment: I need unidirectional mapping. Your solution is using Bidirectional mapping. Bidirectional is easier.

Comment: well you didn't say so.... can you post the code that you use to make the insert?

Comment: Please see the update. I think, there is nothing much to see in my insert code.

Comment: And also, can you say something about the exception, "Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1". It is occurring periodically.

Comment: why are you assigning an Id to the Comment(s) generated when you have set <generator class="native" /> ? this might trigger erroneous behaviour (and maybe the exception you mention)

Comment: I have made correction by not assigning ID to Comments and the following Inner-Exception appeared: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BlogArticleID', table 'Relationships_Test_OneToMany.dbo.Comment'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: NHibernate's steep learning curve is making me more and more frustrated.