# add objects with child collections

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, mapping-model

I have two classes: a Site class and a Phase class. The Site class defines a collection of Phases. Each class corresponds to a database table. The database (SQL Server 2000) has a one to many reference between the two tables such that a given Site can be associated with many Phases but a given Phase can only be associated with a single Site.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Site
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [Editable(true)]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phase> Phases {get; set;}
}

public class Phase
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [Editable(true)]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Editable(true)]
    [StringLength(16)]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual int SiteId {get; set;}
    public virtual Site Site {get; set;}
}
```

I'm using FluentNHibernate to do my mapping. I want to map this in such away that I can create a new Site instance, assign a few Phase instances and make one call to get all instances into the database:

```
Site site = new Site() { Name = "SiteName" };
Phase phase = new Phase() { Name = "PhaseName", Code = "Code" };
Phase otherPhase = new Phase() { Name = "OtherPhaseName" };

site.Phases.Add(phase);
site.Phases.Add(otherPhase);

Session.SaveOrUpdate(site);
```

I have the following mappings in place, but they aren't doing the trick:

```
public class SiteMap : ClassMap<Site>
{
    public SiteMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id).Column("ST_ID").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(p => p.Name).Column("ST_Name");

        HasMany<Phase>(x => x.Phases).KeyColumn("ST_ID").LazyLoad().Inverse().AsSet();
    }
}

public class PhaseMap : ClassMap<Phase>
{
    public PhaseMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id).Column("PH_ID").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(p => p.Name).Column("PH_Name");
        Map(p => p.Code).Column("PH_Code").Nullable();
        Map(p => p.SiteId).Column("ST_ID");

        References<Site>(x => x.Site).Column("ST_ID").LazyLoad(Laziness.Proxy).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    }
}
```

I'm new to NHibernate generally, so I recognize there may be other issues with the mappings shown here that I'm not aware of. Any assistance on how best to map these two classes would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235311/fluent-nhibernate-cascade-issue-trying-to-insert-null-id

Answer (score 1):

```
References<Site>(x => x.Site).Column("ST_ID").LazyLoad(Laziness.Proxy).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
```

Should just be

```
References<Site>(x => x.Site).Column("ST_ID").LazyLoad(Laziness.Proxy);
```

Your Not Insert and Update specifications do not update this column when you're insert or update the table.

You also need to specify Cascade on your one to many end

```
HasMany<Phase>(x => x.Phases).KeyColumn("ST_ID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().LazyLoad().Inverse().AsSet();
```

Comment: Do you need the Cascase.AllDeleteOrphan if the db already has a relationship defined with cascading deletes?

Comment: @Ralf, If your db is configured, you can just specify `Cascade.SaveUpdate` this way your entities will be saved and inserted when the parent is saved or inserted.

Comment: Thanx. I'll play around with this and see where it takes me. I appreciate the input.